# How to insert checkbox in excel using openpyxl python ?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How to insert checkbox in excel using openpyxl python ? 
By using pywin32 we can do the same using following lines of codes

```
cb = sheet.CheckBoxes().Add(Left=sheet.Cells(row,column).Left, 
                            Top=sheet.Cells(row,column).Top, 
                            Width=sheet.Cells(row,column).Width, 
                            Height=sheet.Cells(row,column).Height)
cb.Caption = name_of_checkbox
```

but i want to do using openpyxl ?

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge it's not possible to create new form controls such as checkboxes with `openpyxl`.

However `openpyxl` does allow you to load an existing excel file that already contains form controls, modify the data in the excel file, and then save the excel file with preservation of the form controls. For this to work you must use the method `openpyxl.load_workbook()` with parameter `keep_vba=True` to load the existing excel file (see [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html?highlight=keep_vba#read-an-existing-workbook)).

Comment: It might not work in my case because I always create a new excel containing the data from a database and store it in our common folder. How can I pre define a macro while creating an Excel?

Comment: @pravin Possibility 1: manually create a 'template' excel file that contains just the form controls. Then load this excel file with `openpyxl`, add your data and save as a new excel file. Possibility 2: use the `xlsxwriter` package. This package does support creation of form controls from python code: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_macros.html

Comment: @Xukrao but xlsxwriter doesn't allow to add checkbox.